# Can we connect these two matrices with a piecewise linear path in $GL_n(\mathbb R)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology

Suppose $A\in GL_n(\mathbb R)$ with all eigenvalues lying on the open right half plane, i.e., with positive real part. Let $B = S^{-1} A S$ where $S \in GL_n(\mathbb R)$. I want to define a continuous path $\gamma(t): [0,1] \to GL_n(\mathbb R)$ with $\gamma(0) = A$ and $\gamma(1) = B$. This path certainly exists since $\det(A) = \det(B) > 0$ and $GL_n(\mathbb R)_+$ is connected. I am wondering whether we can make the path $\gamma$ to be piecewise linear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a concrete construction. Since $SL_n(\mathbb R)$ is generated by elementary matrices of the shear type, $P:=\det(A)^{-1/n} A$ can be written as a product $E_1E_2\cdots E_m$ of such shear matrices. Hence $A$ is connected to the identity matrix via a piecewise linear path on $GL_n^+(\mathbb R)$:
$$
A\ \to\ P = E_1E_2\cdots E_m\ \to\ E_1E_2\cdots E_{m-1}\ \to\ \cdots\to\ E_1E_2\to\ E_1\ \to\ I.
$$

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  Consider any continuous path $\gamma: [0,1] \to GL_n(\mathbb R)$.  Since
$\gamma([0,1])$ is compact and $GL_n(\mathbb R)$ is open in $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$, given a norm on $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ there is some $\epsilon > 0$ such that all matrices within distance  $\epsilon$ of $\gamma([0,1])$ are in $GL_n(\mathbb R)$.  Take $t_0 = 0 < t_1 < \ldots < t_n = 1$ so that $\|\gamma(t_j) - \gamma(t_{j+1}\| < 2 \epsilon$ for $j=0 \ldots n-1$.  Then the piecewise linear
function $\tilde{\gamma}$ with $\tilde{\gamma}(t_j) = \gamma(t_j)$ will do.

Comment: I am not following: How do you know that both $A$ and $B$ are on or near a point on the curve $\gamma$

Comment: @Mike: I think $A, B$ are the endpoints of the curve.

Comment: Well, but how do we know then that $\gamma$ stays in $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$? Isn't that what the question was asking for?

Comment: Suppose (toy example) we were to replace $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ with $X=(x_1,\ldots, x_{n^2}) \in \mathbb{R}_{n^2}$; $|x_j| >0$ for each $j=1,\ldots, n^2$. Then $X$ is open, and for any continuous path $\gamma: [0,1] \mapsto X$, there is an $\epsilon$ s.t. all points within distance $\epsilon$ of $\gamma([0,1])$ are in $X$. However, $X$ is **not** path continuous.

Comment: However, $X$ is **not** path continuous. Meanwhile, we cannot a priori assume that for any $A,B \in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ there is a $\gamma$ as in the answer above that starts at $A$, ends at $B$, and stays in $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$, in fact the existence of such a $\gamma$ was the question

Comment: I thought the construction is as follows: (1) We choose a continuous path (not necessarily to be piecewise linear); (2) We use the points described in the answer to get the desired path.

Comment: How do we know that there is such a continuous path from $A$ to $B$ stays in $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ in the first place though? So  I am not seeing how one can just assume (1) in the first place.

Comment: Because $\det(A) = \det(B) > 0$ and $GL_n(\mathbb R)_+$ is path-connected.

Comment: Oh OK. I reread the question. My mistake. The existence of a path as in (1) can indeed be assumed. Yes if we assume such a $\gamma$ then we can indeed make it piecewise linear.